# Enable viewBinding for multiple modules in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

To enable viewBinding , for single module, we can set :

```kotlin
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Inside the module:Gradle `*kts` file.

Is it possible to enable viewBinding for multiple modules at the same time using Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable `viewBinding` by first adding these two extension functions:

```kotlin
fun Project.enableViewBinding() {
    android.buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
}

val Project.android: BaseExtension
    get() = (this as? ExtensionAware)?.extensions?.getByName("android") as BaseExtension
```

Then we can use the new method `enableViewBinding()` enable it for all modules using:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    enableViewBinding()
}
```

Comment: It is interesting usage of gradle API, but define ```viewBinding = true``` in each module of your app should be possible and enough.